# Get indentation and alignment info from PsiWhiteSpace

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-plugin

Consider Java file with the following code (it can be any other language, we use Java as example):

```
public class Foo {

    void foo(int x,
             int y) {}  // line 4

}
```

If IntelliJ is configured to use *smart tabs*, then line 4 will start with one tab (which is called *indentation*) and continued with 9 spaces (which are called *alignment*):

[image]

If IntelliJ is configured to use *spaces*, then line 4 will start with 13 spaces (first four spaces are *indentation*, and next nine spaces are *alignment*):

[image]

I have an object of type [**`PsiWhiteSpace`**](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/b8d3e5ff6f8a8dec721b93632fa51ae55275413d/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/psi/PsiWhiteSpace.java) (which corresponds to both indentation and alignment in line 4). **How can I retrieve information about indentation and alignment**, that is number of chars in indentation and number of chars in alignment?

---

To be more specific here is testcase, which (hopefully) shows what I need:

```js
import com.intellij.application.options.CodeStyle
import com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.StdFileTypes
import com.intellij.psi.PsiDocumentManager
import com.intellij.psi.PsiWhiteSpace
import com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.BasePlatformTestCase

class MyTest : BasePlatformTestCase() {
    fun testExample() {
        val content = """
            public class Foo {

                void foo(int x,
                         int y) {}

            }
        """.trimIndent()

        val psiFile = myFixture.configureByText(StdFileTypes.JAVA, content)
        val document = PsiDocumentManager.getInstance(project).getDocument(psiFile)!!

        val startOffset = document.getLineStartOffset(3)
        val psiWhiteSpace = psiFile.findElementAt(startOffset) as PsiWhiteSpace

//        somehow use psiWhiteSpace to retrieve indent and alignment info:
//        val numberCharsInIndent = ???
//        val numberCharsInAlignment = ???

        val useTabs = CodeStyle.getIndentOptions(psiFile).USE_TAB_CHARACTER
        if (useTabs) {
            assert(numberCharsInIndent == 1)
            assert(numberCharsInAlignment == 9)
        } else {
            assert(numberCharsInIndent == 4)
            assert(numberCharsInAlignment == 9)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to use Indent.getSmartIndent, basically it's a type of indent which tries to collapse multiple indents into single one if proper conditions are met.

Comment: @Kootli method [`getSmartIndent`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/747b08812b83e744d130e315a54cca6b41906f57/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/formatting/Indent.java#L252) takes `Type` as parameter (which is basically an [enum](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/747b08812b83e744d130e315a54cca6b41906f57/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/formatting/Indent.java#L264-L269)).  And I have `PsiWhiteSpace` object. How can I use `getSmartIndent` method to get indent and alignment info from `PsiWhiteSpace` object?